# Looking up for a specific value in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have creater a dataframe as example for different stocks (S1-S10) and their returns.

```
   dates         S1          S2          S3         S4          S5         S6         S7         S8          S9         S10
1   1990 0.22348250 0.060841072 0.045310892 0.25138670 0.114635775 0.06274749 0.32943865 0.11360111 0.007917013 0.198302156
2   1991 0.03936638 0.038865494 0.131434096 0.03934674 0.230446325 0.03907835 0.06295245 0.16572889 0.076442559 0.294755835
3   1992 0.23761437 0.124962186 0.270411728 0.03052463 0.084085012 0.04361429 0.30395396 0.00547834 0.246511480 0.002167857
4   1993 0.02152955 0.026277704 0.558839796 0.25456037 0.009149054 0.04792050 0.04207311 0.01600126 0.010868678 0.023984114
5   1994 0.20228639 0.128382838 0.021868270 0.25458375 0.053629440 0.03955403 0.07121921 0.04028781 0.096863998 0.029832491
6   1995 0.19152864 0.130068221 0.049160473 0.20355840 0.182559298 0.03596715 0.03641926 0.06129930 0.126346577 0.054713422
7   1996 0.23218175 0.111162658 0.108207594 0.11787836 0.011782798 0.27190237 0.14576307 0.01161600 0.014724020 0.080137804
8   1997 0.21180905 0.041096120 0.110944871 0.12150402 0.162546013 0.07068482 0.15903466 0.25115971 0.066643069 0.077361949
9   1998 0.05481769 0.023742951 0.043425701 0.01497890 0.042790468 0.14766542 0.02918536 0.30227679 0.033345436 0.718680714
10  1999 0.01303581 0.008666384 0.006056669 0.01638333 0.014752510 0.01055621 0.04093158 0.11050919 0.133858318 0.166623380
```

Additional, I have a list with Scores (example) for each stock and each year. Every year I will sort the stocks (S1-S10) according to their Score. So for the first year, the sorted table looks as follows:

```
            S3        S5         S9         S1         S4         S6         S7         S2         S8        S10
1990 0.1717736 0.1334458 0.06098671 0.05461788 0.05420852 0.04970982 0.04710081 0.04012442 0.04006076 0.02960202
```

Furthermore, I created a table with the top3 Stocks according to the Score.

```
  ISIN
1   S3
2   S5
3   S9
```

My aim is now to get the returns for the 3 Stocks (S3,S5,S9) for the first year from the first table with all the returns. How can I do that in a simple way which is also able to include in a loop for all the other years.

Thank your very much for your help!

Comment: `your_first_data_frame[1, top3_data_frame$ISIN]`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks a lot! Simple but exactly what I looked for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a table of returns and a table of scores, you can do something like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(returns)
setDT(scores)

merge(
  melt(returns,id="dates",variable.name = "stock", value.name = "return"),
  melt(scores, id="dates",variable.name = "stock", value.name="score")[order(dates,-score)][, .SD[1:3], by=.(dates)][, score_rank:=rep(1:3,10)], 
  by=c("dates", "stock")
)
```

Equivalent tidyverse option

```
inner_join(
  returns %>% pivot_longer(cols = !dates,names_to = "stock",values_to="return"),
  scores %>% pivot_longer(cols=!dates,names_to="stock", values_to = "score") %>% 
    arrange(dates,desc(score)) %>% 
    group_by(dates) %>% 
    slice_head(n = 3) %>% 
    mutate(score_rank=1:3),
  by=c("dates", "stock")
)
```

Output:

```
    dates  stock      return      score score_rank
    <int> <fctr>       <num>      <num>      <int>
 1:  1990     S3 0.045310892 0.17177360          1
 2:  1990     S5 0.114635775 0.13344580          2
 3:  1990     S9 0.007917013 0.06098671          3
 4:  1991     S1 0.039366380 0.67436839          2
 5:  1991     S7 0.062952450 0.64310993          3
 6:  1991    S10 0.294755835 0.72593338          1
 7:  1992     S2 0.124962186 0.94091606          2
 8:  1992     S4 0.030524630 0.91537706          3
 9:  1992     S6 0.043614290 0.95210009          1
10:  1993     S3 0.558839796 0.54894898          3
11:  1993     S4 0.254560370 0.88473749          1
12:  1993     S9 0.010868678 0.85222319          2
13:  1994     S3 0.021868270 0.72819013          3
14:  1994     S9 0.096863998 0.88647338          2
15:  1994    S10 0.029832491 0.89224489          1
16:  1995     S1 0.191528640 0.52342368          3
17:  1995     S9 0.126346577 0.85203851          1
18:  1995    S10 0.054713422 0.68035484          2
19:  1996     S3 0.108207594 0.99714671          1
20:  1996     S9 0.014724020 0.95571008          2
21:  1996    S10 0.080137804 0.93393686          3
22:  1997     S6 0.070684820 0.80203993          1
23:  1997     S9 0.066643069 0.78962934          2
24:  1997    S10 0.077361949 0.76333522          3
25:  1998     S2 0.023742951 0.95326491          2
26:  1998     S4 0.014978900 0.96919113          1
27:  1998     S7 0.029185360 0.85824055          3
28:  1999     S1 0.013035810 0.76017244          3
29:  1999     S6 0.010556210 0.77262997          2
30:  1999     S7 0.040931580 0.79878399          1
    dates  stock      return      score score_rank
```

Input

```
library(data.table)

returns = structure(list(dates = 1990:1999, S1 = c(0.2234825, 0.03936638, 
0.23761437, 0.02152955, 0.20228639, 0.19152864, 0.23218175, 0.21180905, 
0.05481769, 0.01303581), S2 = c(0.060841072, 0.038865494, 0.124962186, 
0.026277704, 0.128382838, 0.130068221, 0.111162658, 0.04109612, 
0.023742951, 0.008666384), S3 = c(0.045310892, 0.131434096, 0.270411728, 
0.558839796, 0.02186827, 0.049160473, 0.108207594, 0.110944871, 
0.043425701, 0.006056669), S4 = c(0.2513867, 0.03934674, 0.03052463, 
0.25456037, 0.25458375, 0.2035584, 0.11787836, 0.12150402, 0.0149789, 
0.01638333), S5 = c(0.114635775, 0.230446325, 0.084085012, 0.009149054, 
0.05362944, 0.182559298, 0.011782798, 0.162546013, 0.042790468, 
0.01475251), S6 = c(0.06274749, 0.03907835, 0.04361429, 0.0479205, 
0.03955403, 0.03596715, 0.27190237, 0.07068482, 0.14766542, 0.01055621
), S7 = c(0.32943865, 0.06295245, 0.30395396, 0.04207311, 0.07121921, 
0.03641926, 0.14576307, 0.15903466, 0.02918536, 0.04093158), 
    S8 = c(0.11360111, 0.16572889, 0.00547834, 0.01600126, 0.04028781, 
    0.0612993, 0.011616, 0.25115971, 0.30227679, 0.11050919), 
    S9 = c(0.007917013, 0.076442559, 0.24651148, 0.010868678, 
    0.096863998, 0.126346577, 0.01472402, 0.066643069, 0.033345436, 
    0.133858318), S10 = c(0.198302156, 0.294755835, 0.002167857, 
    0.023984114, 0.029832491, 0.054713422, 0.080137804, 0.077361949, 
    0.718680714, 0.16662338)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

scores = structure(list(dates = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 
1996, 1997, 1998, 1999), S3 = c(0.1717736, 0.0826668301597238, 
0.150193300796673, 0.548948981100693, 0.728190132649615, 0.460348989348859, 
0.99714671052061, 0.570633312221617, 0.152109869290143, 0.165023590438068
), S5 = c(0.1334458, 0.203297924017534, 0.335005605360493, 0.512913924409077, 
0.641863208264112, 0.474032786209136, 0.105274769943208, 0.261479944223538, 
0.231785625452176, 0.432228550780565), S9 = c(0.06098671, 0.141129324445501, 
0.633016546489671, 0.852223185822368, 0.886473377235234, 0.852038505952805, 
0.95571007928811, 0.789629340171814, 0.632387412479147, 0.634164091199636
), S1 = c(0.05461788, 0.674368392676115, 0.821303177857772, 0.225072045112029, 
0.319124778266996, 0.523423680569977, 0.0977244963869452, 0.230580852134153, 
0.164935799082741, 0.760172437177971), S4 = c(0.05420852, 0.395722589921206, 
0.915377061348408, 0.884737493470311, 0.0933721493929625, 0.349144774954766, 
0.883127712178975, 0.617036611540243, 0.969191126758233, 0.536874044453725
), S6 = c(0.04970982, 0.450498258927837, 0.952100092312321, 0.273910752963275, 
0.35602370928973, 0.327704650117084, 0.521468475693837, 0.802039931761101, 
0.557341758161783, 0.772629965795204), S7 = c(0.04710081, 0.643109925789759, 
0.419676352757961, 0.200271958485246, 0.0809331068303436, 0.344844142906368, 
0.683793851174414, 0.187082261545584, 0.858240547589958, 0.798783992184326
), S2 = c(0.04012442, 0.238682345021516, 0.94091605511494, 0.0884579077828676, 
0.0896228931378573, 0.204645883990452, 0.561662087915465, 0.746485061943531, 
0.953264913987368, 0.728270860854536), S8 = c(0.04006076, 0.118304285453632, 
0.784008525079116, 0.0789051840547472, 0.642171601299196, 0.421911529498175, 
0.327139612054452, 0.517780556110665, 0.449964761035517, 0.367198353400454
), S10 = c(0.02960202, 0.725933377398178, 0.0461170475464314, 
0.509178411681205, 0.892244888702407, 0.680354839190841, 0.933936856221408, 
0.763335221679881, 0.473462641937658, 0.111220514168963)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: just as a short follow up question: Why is the command  "mutate(score_rank=1:3) " able to correctly rank the score and not just repeat 1,2,3 over the whole time?

Comment: @Ramon, actually, it is the `arrange(dates, desc(score))` that allows the correct sorting.. When I then group by `dates`, and use `slice_head(n=3)`, the first three rows in descending order of score are pulled for each dates group... The `mutate(score_rank=1:3)` does just generate a single sequence of 1,2,3, but does it by each group of dates.... Since within each group, the data are sorted by descending score, this sequence of 1,2,3 turns out to be "correct"

Comment: thank you very much! this helps me a lot for further steps

Comment: Do you see a possibility to do the scoring on a yearly basis and the take  the monthly returns of the stocks ranking on the first 3 places until the next score appears one year later? This would give the opportunity to better calculate standard deviation and other risk/return metrics of the portfolio?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ramon not sure what you mean, but I'm sure its possible. Can you post another question? Is the dataset the same/different?